# Clustering point data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clustering, filter

Working in QGIS 3.4.1 Madeira

I have a layer with many data points, for visual purposes I wish to remove some of the overlaying points.

Is there a simple way to perform some sort of clustering/filtering of point based on their relative distance to each other?

I found the Plugin calls "ClusterPoint" but cannot find where it is or how to use it.

Comment: https://anitagraser.com/2017/06/13/even-more-aggregations-qgis-point-cluster-renderer/

This seems like a place to start.

Comment: After installing the plugin, you'll find an option in the Layer Styling Panel called "Point cluster."

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with the "point cluster" symbology.

Before:

[image]

Rightclick on your point layer -> Properties... -> Symbology -> and chose "Point cluster"

Close points (you can define this parametre) will be replaced by a single symbol and the number of points replaced will be indicated.

[image]