How to group nodes in Overpass API query that are near other nodes?
My goal is to fetch waste_basket nodes, where any nodes within 50m of other waste_basket nodes are grouped together into one.  All other nodes are fetched as-is.
I started attempting to find nodes that are 50m from each other as a starting point but it is already failing to find nearby nodes.  What am I doing wrong here?
[out:json] [timeout:25];
area[name="London"]->.searchArea;

node["amenity"="waste_basket"](area.searchArea)->.baskets;
node["amenity"="waste_basket"](around.baskets:50)->.near_baskets;

.near_baskets;

out geom;


around:50 means that node should be within 50m, which includes 0m distance. This way your query simply returns all waste_baskets in the search area.
You would have to iterate over each single node, check if number of nodes in 50m distance is larger than 1 (thereby excluding the current node), then only output some representative of this group. This is roughly comparable to the Isolated buildings example.
However, I would strongly advise against using this approach, since it is very time and resource consuming and in the end not feasible at all. Overpass API is not a good tool for this task.
Instead, I'd recommend to use Overpass API only to fetch all waste baskets, and use your own logic outside of Overpass API for the grouping.

This is a one-off approach where I'd run it like once a year so I am less concerned about resources and I actually intend to run it in a smaller area.  So what I'm hearing is that this is not possible in Overpass API?  I am using QGIS to consume it, and I am not sure if that even supports logic to iterate over the nodes so I may need to start writing custom scripts..

Maybe load the waste baskets into a Postgresql database and use PostGIS for grouping / clustering. This site probably has lots of answers on the topic already, such as https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388848/clustering-and-combining-points-in-postgis
You could consume the query results later on from QGIS.
Maybe you could also explore some QGIS plugins such as https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/clusterpoints/ to do the clustering there, and use the QuickOSM plugin to download the waste basket into QGIS initially.

I was able to cluster it in QGIS easily this way: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303193/clustering-point-data-in-qgis
